# Need to change MUL key to PRI key

Tags: mysql

Initially the Primary Key was

> (caseId,osName)

```
   +--------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
    | Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
    +--------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
    | createdBy          | varchar(200)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | createdOn          | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
    | osName             | varchar(200)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | caseId             | varchar(100)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
    | issueType          | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | observationState   | varchar(60)   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | problemSolving     | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | structure          | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | logicalTransition  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | ownership          | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | expectationSetting | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | empathy            | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | valueAdd           | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | comments           | varchar(2000) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
    | version            | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
    | showcase_escalate  | varchar(30)   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | ringback_state     | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | trt_state          | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | srp_state          | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
    | id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
    +--------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

In the above schema, `id` was `AUTO INCREMENT`. I removed that so I could make `caseId as PRIMARY KEY`. But since there are multiple records with same caseId I am not able to make the change.

At the end I just want caseId as my Primary Key.

Initially the Primary Key was (caseId,osName).

Comment: You need a policy for the duplicate rows. Do you want to keep only one?

Comment: Keep only one meaning?

Comment: Yes you can't have unique caseId without keeping one and throwing the others

Comment: Correct. So I want to throw away the others and only keep the latest entry.

Answer (score 0):

As defined in the [MySQL Glossary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_primary_key):

> #### primary key
>
> A set of columns -- and by implication, the index based on this set of columns -- that can uniquely identify every row in a table. As such, it must be a unique index that does not contain any `NULL` values.
>
> InnoDB requires that every table has such an index (also called the ***clustered index*** or ***cluster index***), and organizes the table storage based on the column values of the primary key.
>
> When choosing primary key values, consider using arbitrary values (a ***synthetic key***) rather than relying on values derived from some other source (a ***natural key***).
>
> See Also [clustered index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_clustered_index), [index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_index), [natural key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_natural_key), [synthetic key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_synthetic_key).

Since you have multiple records with the same value for `caseId`, `caseId` alone cannot "*uniquely identify every row*" in your table; and therefore `caseId` alone **cannot** be a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: How do I remove these duplicates?

Comment: @ArpanDas: To be clear, you are asking how to delete a whole bunch of records from your table so that each `caseId` will now appear only once (whereas, originally, it could appear once per `osName`).  Are you *absolutely certain* that you want to discard all but one `osName` per `caseId`?  How is it decided which one `osName` is to be kept (and thus which others are to be deleted)?

Comment: Lets say caseId is constant for 3 distinct values of osName -> This results in 3 rows.

I want to keep the latest entry i.e. the one with the latest timestamp. 
How would I go about doing that ?

Comment: @ArpanDas: `DELETE FROM myTable WHERE (caseId, createdOn) NOT IN (SELECT caseId, MAX(createdOn) FROM myTable GROUP BY caseId)`.

Comment: Post which I use 

`ALTER TABLE mytable DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY ( caseId );`

Would that be correct?